# Cannot get result of sed pipe as argument for cd

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a working `echo` + sed command

```
echo %cd% | sed -E 's#(C\:\\\some\\\path\\\)([-_A-Za-z0-9]+).*#\1\2#g'
```

I cannot get its result to work as `cd` argument (Windows, cmder)

```
~~=cd $(echo %cd% | sed -E 's#(C\:\\\some\\\path\\\)([-_A-Za-z0-9]+).*#\1\2#g')
```

The error:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: unknown option to `s'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
's#(C\:\\\some\\\path\\\)([-_A-Za-z0-9]+).*#\1\2#g'
```

Should be

```
's#(C\:\\some\\path\\)([-_A-Za-z0-9]+).*#\1\2#g'
```

You were removing the special meaning from the first ")" with the `"\)"`.

But '%cd%' has no meaning in Linux or Bash.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said - the sed part works for me just fine. Stripping the backslashes actually fails the command with syntax error. My question was rather about using the output in `cd`. Running in cmder, on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the tags linux and bash from your question?